# Copying IOS from TFTP problem

Tags: interface, tftp

I have a Cisco 4503 switch that had its IOS completely wiped.  I have managed to boot from TFTP.  the instructions I have tell me to switch the ethernet cable from the management port to a standard 10/100 port after booting from, TFTP, but the problem is the fastethernet1 interface is now down.  I was able to ping the TFTP server before I booted from it.  But now the interface is down and I can't copy the .bin file to flash now.  How do I bring the interface up?  I am very new to this and it's just a hobby, nothing critical.  Please help.

Answer (score 5):

> I was able to ping the TFTP server before I booted from it. But now
> the interface is down and I can't copy the .bin file to flash now.

That's by design. The FastEthernet Port on the Cat4500 Supervisor Engines only works while the system is in ROMmon (see https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-4000-series-switches/24061-149.html) for details. Quote (emphasize by me):

> These Supervisor Engines also provide an Ethernet Management port
> (10/100 Base T), **which is available only from ROMmon** mode and can be
> configured to download a new valid image through TFTP from a TFTP
> process.

You now seem to have booted from TFTP successfully, which means the switch is running IOS (or CatOS, for that matter) - and the FastEthernet management port must now be down.

You'll have to apply some (basic) port and IP configuration to (one of the ports of) the running switch, and connect that port to the same network as before (where the TFTP Server is reachable), possibly even connecting  the TFTP server directly to a switchport on one of the line cards.

Alternative: While in ROMmon, use the management ethernet port to *download* the software image right away, *instead of booting* from the TFTP server and having to re-dowload the image afterwards.